# Is $C_b(L,E)$ a function module?

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

**Notation**: Let $K$ be a compact Hausdorff space.
Denote $C(K)$ to be the set of all scalar-valued continuous functions on $K.$

In the book '[Isometries on Banach Spaces: Vector-Valued Function Spaces and Operator Spaces](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1584883863)' by Fleming and Jamison, page $18,$ they gave a definition of a function module.

> **Definition**: A *Banach function module* or *function module* is a triple $(K,(Y_t)_{t\in K}, Y),$ where $K$ is a nonempty compact Hausdorff space (the base space), $(Y_t)_{t\in K}$ is a family of Banach spaces (the component spaces), and $Y$ a closed subspace of $\prod_{t\in K}Y_t$ such that the following conditions are satisfied:
>
> (i) $hy\in Y$ for $y\in Y$ and $h\in C(K)$
>
> (ii) $t\mapsto \|y(t)\|$ is an upper semicontinuous function for every $y\in Y,$
>
> (iii) $Y_t=\{y(t):y\in Y\},$
>
> (iv) $\overline{\{t\in K:Y_t\neq \{0\}\}} = K$

Let $E$ be a Banach space and $L$ be a locally compact space.
Denote $C_b(L,E)$ to be the set of all $E$-valued bounded continuous functions on $L.$

> **Question**: Is $C_b(L,E)$ a function module?

Based on Fleming and Jamison, if $L$ is not compact, one can take its Stone-Cech compactification $\beta L$ and $Y_t = E$ if $t\in L$ and $Y_t=\{0\}$ if $t\in \beta L \setminus L.$

However, I do not know that the compactified space is a function module or not.

Comment: $C(\beta L)=C_b(L)$ (more precisely, the restriction mapping is an isometry) should be helpful.

Comment: But space of interest is vector-valued not scale-valued.